# why does run rails test:controllers get articles_index_url 'ArgumentError: Range unspecified.'?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

when run `rails test:controllers`

```
E

Error:
ArticlesControllerTest#test_should_get_index:
ArgumentError: Range unspecified. Specify the :in, :within, :maximum, :minimum, or :is option.
    app/models/comment.rb:3:in `<class:Comment>'
    app/models/comment.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'


bin/rails test test/controllers/articles_controller_test.rb:4
```

under is comment.rb constraint

```
class Comment < ApplicationRecord

  validates :name, presence: true, length: { mimimum: 5 }
  validates :description, presence: true, length: { minimum: 5 }

  belongs_to :user_id
  belongs_to :article_id
end
```

that test file is:

```
require 'test_helper'

class ArticlesControllerTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  test "should get index" do
    get articles_index_url
    assert_response :success
  end

end
```

routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users

  resources :articles

  root 'articles#index'
end
```

i was look for routes table, that path is right, but when run `test` that would be point out `ArgumentError: Range unspecified.`

Comment: Can you please post `app/models/comment.rb`

Comment: Its a simple typo. You have `mimimum` not `minimum` on line 3 in `comment.rb`